# How to get edittext position in Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, listadapter, simpleadapter

I am working on `ListView` having `EditText` inside.I have used four `EditText` in each item of `ListView`.I am facing problem with getting the position of `EditText` in the `ListView`. Below is my code. I am able to fetch the position of `TextView`,but while fetching the position of `EditText` I am facing problem.

```
           lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {


                    myproductpercarton = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtorderamount);
                    final String ssss =(String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtorderamount)).getText();             
                    mytotalprice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtprice);
                    mm = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.mycheck);
                    mm.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    mm.setFocusable(true);
                    mm2 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.mynewcheck);
                    mm2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    mm2.setFocusable(true);
                    myorderprice = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtorderby);
                    myorderprice.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    myorderprice.setFocusable(true);
                    mycartonno = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtordercarton);
                    mycartonno.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    mycartonno.setFocusable(true);


                    myproductno = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtproduct);
                    myproductno.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    myproductno.setFocusable(true);

                    myproductno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            String myprodpercart;
                            map = (HashMap<String, String>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
                            HashMap<String, String> map2 = (HashMap<String, String>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
                            HashMap<String, String> map3 = (HashMap<String, String>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);


                            double orderId4;
                            double mycarton2;
                            double mynewcart;
                            double myprodno2;
                            double mycartquantity;
                            double mytotal;
                            String mynoocarton;
                            double mynoocarton44;
                            int myprodno3;                           
                            String temp=mycartonno.getText().toString();
                            String contents = mycartonno.getText().toString();
                            orderId4 = new Double(map.get(TAG_PRODUCTPERCARTON));
                            Log.d("MyOrderId :: ", String.valueOf(orderId4));
                            mycartonprice2 = map.get(TAG_PRODUCTPERCARTON2);
                            Log.d("MyCartonPrice :: ", String.valueOf(mycartonprice2));                             
                            mynoocarton = mycartonno.getText().toString();
                            mynoocarton44 = new Double(mycartonno.getText().toString());

                            mycarton2 = new Double(mynoocarton);
                            mynewcart = new Double(mycartonprice2);
                            myprodno2 = new Double(orderId4 * mycarton2);
                            myprodno3 = new Integer((int) myprodno2);
                            mycartquantity = new Double(mycartonno.getText().toString());
                            Log.d("MyCartonNo :: ", mycartonno.getText().toString());
                            Log.d("MyCartonNo2 :: ",contents);                            
                            mytotal = new Double(mycartquantity * mynewcart);
                            String mynoocarton3 = String.valueOf(mynoocarton44);                               
                            String total = String.valueOf(mytotal);
                            String mm = String.valueOf(myprodno3);                             
                            mycartonno.setText(mynoocarton3);
                            myproductno.setText(mm);
                            mytotalprice.setText(total);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ssss + " " + mynewcart + "----" + mm + "  " + total,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                    mydiscount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtdiscount);
                    mydiscount.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    mydiscount.setFocusable(true);
                }
            });
```

Comment: what is the issue ? means where you are not able to get position ?

Comment: Share code of your list item layout

Comment: What "problem" are you facing?

Comment: I am not able to set the position of  myproductno.setText(mm);Means If I am in fourth row after entering the value in 3rd row and from 4th row if I again click on edittext of 3rd row then it is showing me the value of 4th row and not 3rd row

Comment: First of all you should initialize your EditText and every view inside your custom listview inside your Adapter class not inside your listview itemClick. Then there you should provide the click event for the edittext and whatnot. Can you provide you Adapter class code...?

Comment: Thanks akhil for your solution.Actaully my problem is already solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself and now its working fine. I just have taken another `textview` and two new `edittext` inside `setOnClickListener`. I just added below code inside `setOnClickListener`.

```
TextView mynewtotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtprice);
EditText mycartonprod = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtordercarton);
mycartonprod.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mycartonprod.setFocusable(true);
EditText myprod = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtproduct);
myprod.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
myprod.setFocusable(true);
```